# $_GET to accept values with space

Tags: javascript, php, html, sqlsrv

I checked all the possible solutions here, unfortunately it won't work. What seems to be the problem with my code?

I tried the following.

urldecode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

str_replace http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

But no luck.

I tried the following in `isset`

`$accounttitle = $_GET['accounttitle'];`

`urlencode($_GET["accounttitle"])`

`$accounttitle = str_replace(" ", "", $accounttitle );`

Here's my `isset`

```
  if(isset($_GET['accounttitle'])){
    $accounttitle = $_GET['accounttitle'];
  } ?>
```

Here's my form

```
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <!--<a href="#addnew" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New</a> --> 
<div class="form-group">              
<?php
$sql = "SELECT accountcode, accounttitle, accounttype FROM earningsamendmentaccount";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
?>
<label for="select_account_title" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Select Account Title</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<select class="form-control" id="select_account_title" style="text-transform:uppercase" required>
<option value="">PLEASE SELECT OPTION</option>
<?php 

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{

    echo "<option value=".$row['accounttitle'].">".$row['accounttitle']."</option>";

}
  ?>
</select>
</div>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

Here's my script

```
$(function(){
  $('#select_account_title').change(function(){
    window.location.href = 'earnings_amendment.php?accounttitle='+$(this).val();
  });
});
</script>
```

I can `echo()` but it won't work on values with space.

Comment: what is the value `$_GET['accounttitle']` is it the `username` or a full `names` for your `user`.

Comment: @dean it composes values like ````ADVANCES TO EMPLOYEES````, ````OUTING EXPENSES````, etc.

Comment: Okay, this will be a complex code. Just like a name, you need to add `-` between words spaces and the assign the updated value to your  `$_GET['accounttitle']` link.

Comment: You need: `?accounttitle='+encodeURIComponent($(this).val());`  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: @drew010 This works as well, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not **receiving** `$_GET` but rather with your outgoing link.

```
<select class="form-control" id="select_account_title" style="text-transform:uppercase" required>
  <option value="">PLEASE SELECT OPTION</option>
  <?php while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
    <option value="<?= urlencode($row['accounttitle'])?>"><?= $row['accounttitle'] ?></option>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: you sir, are a live saver! thank you so much! I was to focused on receiving the output, I didn't know the problem was with the ````<option>````

Comment: Tunnel vision is easy to get ;). Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I prefer trim 'trim()' php function not string replace.